# Passing a model from a DLL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC3 application which has a reference to DLL. This DLL is called up on exception. The DLL method which is called should return a viewname along with model.
Now the problem i am facing is

1. I am not able to pass a model to a view from a DLL.
2. The method which are used to pass a model like View() and RedirectToAction() are not accessible.
3. The methods which are accessible are RedirectResult() and RedirectToRouteResult() which does not accept any model.

To Elaborate More.
I have an MVC application in a solution. In same solution i have an DLL in same solution. This DLL is used by MVC application. This DLL consists of a DLL reference of System.Web.MVC. Now i have a class with a method in the DLL as
public static ActionResult HandleException()
        {
            return ;
        }
Here this method should use something like 
return View("SomeView",SomeModel);
But this method (View()) is not accessible in a method of a class in DLL.

Comment: can you post some code here? (The code which uses the DLL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you can.
   Add a reference to the DLL in Web.config, the specify the type and namespace in `@model`.
2. Your situation is unclear.
   You're probably looking for the `ViewResult` class.
   **EDIT**:

   ```
   return new ViewResult {
       ViewName = "something",
       ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(yourModel)
   };
   ```
3. Classes aren't methods

Comment: Please provide more detail.  How are you using it?

Comment: Situation is, I have an DLL which i have referenced in my MVC application. 
Through this DLL i need to show an view which has a model. The Situation is                                         public static ActionResult HandleException()                        
{
 return View("SomeView", SomeModel)
} 
Here in DLL i am not able to get any method or a class which will passs the model to my MVC application.

Comment: As I said, you're looking for `ViewResult`.

Comment: Any perticular class which I would be able to pass the model to my MVC app.

Comment: @user: You can use any model you want.

Comment: I think you are not getting it. I am not able to pass the model from dll to MVC application.

Comment: Why not? What happens?  You probably forgot to add a reference or namespace.

Comment: You personally create it and add the reference of System.Web.MVC to your DLL application, and try to pass a model with a view to MVC application through a DLL method. You wont get View method or RedirectToAction() method.

Comment: @User: Yes.  **You're looking for the `ViewResult` class.**  Set the `ViewName` property, and set the `ViewData` property to a `ViewDataDictionary` around your model.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, Can you give some code or something.